# Entity Framework slow with optional where clauses

Tags: performance, entity-framework

Below is a snippit of simplified version of a problem I am having with Entity Framework v4 where the first load seems to take around 30 seconds on a table with 36 rows!

After that it is very quick to load until you change the search params, then it takes 30 seconds again but once that combination of search params has been done once it is quick.

This is repeated each time a different combination of params is used.

```
IQueryable<User> result= GetAllUsers();

if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(firstNameSearchParam))
{
    result = result.Where(u => u.firstname.contains(firstNameSearchParam))
}    

if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(lastNameSearchParam))
{
    result = result.Where(u => u.lastname.contains(lastNameSearchParam))
}

Var ret = result.ToArray();
```

Any ideas would be really appreciated.

I'm not sure if [pre-compiling the views](http://blog.willbeattie.net/2010/04/pre-generating-views-in-entity.html) will help. I tried but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Where is the time spent? Profile the app, or pause the debugger.

Comment: Yep done that, the time is in ToArray(), which is when the queryable is actually executed in sql but the query in sql takes a fraction of a second. I suspect that because its the first time, EF is building views or something, which is why it is quick the second time. I'm not sure if it is possible to get EF to per build views for dynamically generated queries like this.

Comment: The time is not spent in ToArray directly (can't be because ToArray knows nothing about SQL). The call stack goes deeper. Enable "Show external code" and look at the actual stack.

Comment: It might be worth your time to do a prototype of the same query using EF5 or EF6 RC. EF5 can be up to 6x faster than EF4 in some circumstances. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/14/sneak-preview-entity-framework-5-0-performance-improvements.aspx

Comment: I have encapsulated the query into a console app and upgraded ef 4.0 to the ef 5 nugget package and changed the project to use .net 4.5. The query still runs just as slowly first time and quickly for subsequent calls.

Comment: @usr. Your are right that it is not ToArray() directly but it is this call that triggers EF to take the queryable and build and execute the sql query. It is this that takes ages first time and is pretty instant for subsequent calls.

Comment: This information does not help. We already knew that. Profile the app do see what part of EF is taking a long time. That might give a clue to how to improve the situation. The first EF might take long, but further queries (even different ones) should be fast. You say that each "where combination" takes a long startup pause. Profile what happens during that pause.

Comment: Does `context.Database.Initialize(true)` take 30 seconds as well (if you perform this before any query) in your console test app? Then the problem is likely view generation. (Is it a complex model with lots of entity classes and relationships?)

Answer (score 0):

how long it takes when you execute the query from the sql side?

you can use this idea mentioned by scott here on this link [Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

and i think this will work with you also with Entity Framework, and there is another idea that you can use the entity framework metadata

hope that this will help you

regards

Comment: If I grab the sql from the profiler and execute that it is virtually instant, so I am pretty confident that its not the query that is slow but the way ef is building the query and mapping it to dto's.

Comment: kindly, check this article for more information http://geekswithblogs.net/DavidBarrett/archive/2012/02/06/using-entity-framework-to-query-dynamic-types.aspx

Comment: the best way and to make your work more easy is: use dynamic string builder to build the where clause, then you can use the [DbContext].Database.SqlQuery<YourClass>(YourSql)

Comment: if you want an example i can edit my answer to show you a sample example.